# Rails: Optimize querying maximum values from associated table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I need to show a list of partners and the maximum value from the `reservation_limit` column from `Klass` table.

```
Partner  has_many    :klasses
Klass    belongs_to  :partner

# Partner controller
def index
  @partners = Partner.includes(:klasses)
end

# view
<% @partners.each do |partner| %>
  Up to <%= partner.klasses.maximum("reservation_limit") %> visits per month
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately the query below runs for every single `Partner`.

```
SELECT MAX("klasses"."reservation_limit") FROM "klasses" WHERE "klasses"."partner_id" = $1  [["partner_id", 1]]
```

If there are 40 partners then the query will run 40 times. How do I optimize this?

---

edit: Looks like there's a [limit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit) method in rails so I'm changing the `limit` in question to `reservation_limit` to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two forms of SQL to efficiently retrieve this information, and I'm assuming here that you want a result for a partner even where there is no klass record for it

The first is:

```
   select partners.*,
          max(klasses.limit) as max_klasses_limit
     from partners
left join klasses on klasses.partner_id = partners.id
 group by partner.id
```

Some RDBMSs require that you use "group by partner.*", though, which is potentially expensive in terms of the required sort and the possibility of it spilling to disk.

On the other hand you can add a clause such as:

```
having("max(klasses.limit) > ?", 3)
```

... to efficiently filter the partners by their value of maximum klass.limit

The other is:

```
   select partners.*,
          (Select max(klasses.limit)
             from klasses
            where klasses.partner_id = partners.id) as max_klasses_limit
     from partners
```

The second one does not rely on a group by, and in some RDBMSs may be effectively transformed internally to the first form, but may execute less efficiently by the subquery being executed once per row in the partners table (which would stil be much faster than the raw Rails way of actually submitting a query per row).

The Rails ActiveRecord forms of these would be:

```
Partner.joins("left join klasses on klasses.partner_id = partners.id").
        select("partners.*, max(klasses.limit) as max_klasses_limit").
        group(:id)
```

... and ...

```
Partner.select("partners.*, (select max(klasses.limit)
               from klasses
               where klasses.partner_id = partners.id) as max_klasses_limit")
```

Which of these is actually the most efficient is probably going to depend on the RDBMS and even the RDBMS version.

If you don't need a result when there is no klass for the partner, or there is always guaranteed to be one, then:

```
Partner.joins(:klasses).
        select("partners.*, max(klasses.limit) as max_klasses_limit").
        group(:id)
```

Either way, you can then reference

```
partner.max_klasses_limit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial query brings all the information you need. You only need to work with it as you would work with a regular array of objects.

Change

```
Up to <%= partner.klasses.maximum("reservation_limit") %> visits per month
```

to

```
Up to <%= partner.klasses.empty? ? 0 : partner.klasses.max_by { |k| k.reservation_limit }.reservation_limit %> visits per month
```

---

What `maximum("reservation_limit")` does it to trigger an **Active Record** query `SELECT MAX...`. But you don't need this, as you already have all the information you need to process the maximum in your array.

**Note**
Using `.count` on an Active Record result will trigger an extra `SELECT COUNT...` query!
Using `.length` will not.

Comment: I tried but it shows up as `Up to #<Klass:0x007fe9b291bec0> visits per month`

Comment: Check my updated answer, you need a `.limit` at the end.

Comment: Now I'm getting: `undefined method 'limit' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: This is highly inefficient because it relies on sorting at Ruby side, whereas all what you are doing in Ruby should be performed at database level as the database is generally more efficient (without considering the query will not have to return all the data for klasses and Ruby will not allocate a large number of objects effectively wasting a lot of memory).

Comment: @ i.am.noob you get that because some of your partners have no classes. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It generally helps if you start writing the query in pure SQL and then extract it into ActiveRecord or Arel code.

ActiveRecord is powerful, but it tends to force you to write highly inefficient queries as soon as you derail from the standard CRUD operations.

Here's your query

```
Partner
    .select('partners.*, (SELECT MAX(klasses.reservation_limit) FROM klasses WHERE klasses.partner_id = partners.id) AS maximum_limit')
    .joins(:klasses).group('partners.id')
```

It is a single query, with a subquery. However the subquery is optimized to run only once as it can be parsed ahead and it doesn't run N+1 times.

The code above fetches all the partners, joins them with the `klasses` records and thanks to the join it can compute the aggregate maximum. Since the join effectively creates a cartesian product of the records, you then need to group by the `partners.id` (which in fact is required in any case by the `MAX` aggregate function).

The key here is the `AS maximum_limit` that will assign a new attribute to the `Partner` instances returned with the value of the count.

```
partners = Partner.select ...
partners.each do |partner|
  puts partner.maximum_limit
end
```

Comment: I see a couple of issues here: when you use "join(:klasses}", that is not creating a cartesian product, it is simply inner joining the products with the klasses. The reason you need the group('partners.id') is to then reduce the set to one row per partner, but you can do that by just not joining with klasses in the first place. If you use a subquery to get the max(klasses.limit) than that join was redundant, and only serves to ensure that no partners will be returned unless they have at least one klass record.

Comment: @DavidAldridge you're right, I originally started with a different approach based only on the join, but then I ended up with the subquery. I'll leave the join in place as one of the issue the user had in other comments was the presence of partner with no classes. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This will return max. limits in one select for an array of `parthner_ids`:

```
parthner_ids = @partners.map{|p| p.id}
data = Klass.select('MAX("limit") as limit', 'partner_id').where(partner_id: parthner_ids).group('partner_id')
@limits = data.to_a.group_by{|d| d.id}
```

You can now integrate it into your view:

```
<% @partners.each do |partner| %>
  Up to <%= @limits[partner.id].limit %> visits per month
<% end %>
```

Comment: There's no need for him to write a monstrous query when all the information he needs to calculate the maximum is already there.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu he asks for MAX in one select, not for each partner separately.

Comment: How do I get `parthner_ids`?

Comment: `parthner_ids = @partners.map{|p| p.id}`

Comment: @dimakura He wants to list that maximum for each partner, so to me it looks like he wants the maximum for each individual class. Of course, I might be wrong, but in that case it doesn't make much sense to do it this way :)

Comment: @i.am.noob I've also added code on how to integrate it into your view